# Parent DIV to inherit width (%) from child div

Tags: css

I am currently trying to figure out a way to be able to have a layout that has a bottom-up, content-oriented resizing behavior.

I have the following situation: https://codepen.io/Flash1232/pen/JJYPVQ

What is wrong here is obviously that the `wrapper` divs do not wrap around the `table` divs. Now is there any solution for this involving just plain CSS and HTML or do I have to write something in JS like "set wrapper width to the width of its inner div"?

Thanks in advance for any clues!

Comment: You need JS for that. CSS doesn't go up the tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the definition of the `width` attribute.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/width

> Percentages:  refer to the width of the containing block

If you set width to 150%, you explicitly say, that the child should be bigger than the parent. You can not expect, that the parent has the same width like the child, if you force the child to be wider.

Comment: That's good to know. How can I make the wrappers wrap the Content (and the column match the wrapper's width) and still be able to set the width of the tables in percent of their own width?

Comment: What is "own width"? Is it the width the browser calculates for the content, if no width has been specified? Specify borders, margins or padding, if the column should be wider than necessary.

Comment: "Own width" indeed means the table's content.

Answer (score 3):

Man i solved my problem with `display:flex` on parent element :)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using a flexbox. Please see below. If there is anything that needs to be different, just let me know.

```css
.outer-div {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  width: 800px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.area {
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  border: 5px solid red;
  background: white;
  margin: 10px 40px 10px 10px;
}

.column {
  background: green;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  border: 5px solid yellow;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.table {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.violet {
  background: violet;
  width: 120%;
  height: 80px;
}

.red {
  background: red;
  width: 150%;
  height: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.icons {
  Background: yellow;
  float: right;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-div">
  <div class="area">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="table red">
          <span>***Table Content***</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="table violet">
          <span>***Table Content***</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="table violet">
          <span>***Table Content***</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="icons">
    <p>Icon</p>
    <p>Icon</p>
    <p>Icon</p>
    <p>Icon</p>
    <p>Icon</p>
    <p>Icon</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I should have mentioned also that the width percentage of the inner tables must be taken into consideration and the wrappers should wrap around the tables regarding their additional width and thus also `column` divs should then fit to that size.